# storing `std::tm` in SQLite

Tags: c++, sqlite, c++11, time

I have an `std::tm` struct like `std::tm epochStart = {};`

I set everything I need.

I am wondering how I can store this in SQLite so I can read it back easier later to do time comparisons? I was hoping I could store the whole struct in a blob and later read it back from the database, cast it as a `std::tm` and be on my way..

Can anyone share some thoughts on how to achieve this?

Comment: `std::tm` is a POD; assuming the SQLite function to write a binary blob takes a pointer to a buffer, and size, you should be able to declare a `buffer[sizeof(std::tm)]` and `memcpy` back and forth.

Comment: this is interesting, I'll try it. How did you know `std::tm` was a POD?

Comment: Because it's inherited from C

Comment: Thank you, I see it now at the bottom: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/tm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storing a `struct tm` as a blob is possible, but is dangerous if any program that accesses this database ever changes architecture or compiler version.

To store a timestamp, you should use one of the [supported date/time datatypes](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#datetime).

To store it in the default format (a string), use code like this:

```
char buffer[20];
strftime(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", &tm);
```

To store it as a single number, convert it with something like `mktime`.